# How to play a specific child's audio?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

Say I have a `GameObject` with 2 or more children on it, which each has an `AudioSource` attached to it, like so:

```
PowerUp
    Audio 1
    Audio 2
    Audio 3
```

How do I determine which Audio to play? I know you can access child values like `gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<AudioSource>().Play();` but wouldn't that play all 3 audio clips at once?

Is it possible to do something like (I know this doesn't exist) `gameObject.GetChildren."Name".Play()`?

Comment: Well, how *do* you determine which audio to play? If you're looking to play one specific clip, you need a way to identify which clip it is. If you want to play one at random, that's also fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the audio from a specific child you could use `Find` to first find the child and then access the audio as such:

```
GameObject child = this.transform.Find("CHILD_NAME").gameObject;
child.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
```

*assuming that "this" is the parent object*

Comment: That could work, but seems like a lot of effort to play something in a child?

Comment: @Tom it's just an additional line of code. I cannot boot up unity and try though so I'm not sure if there is a better way. This was just off the top of my head.

Comment: Also this could be merged into one line like such: `this.transform.Find("CHILD_NAME").gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();`